# Am I facing any risk to do a www to non-www redirect in nginx if I didn't get a SSL key for the www domain?

Tags: nginx

The nginx directives works fine:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.example.org;
  return 301 $scheme://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

However, I don't have a SSL certificate for the `www.` domain (I only have one for the `non-www` domain).

Am I over-worried?

Comment: Over-worried because? What's your question about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect, you establish a new connection. Your new connection will be with https and ssl. I think that answers your question and concern about security.